# How can I use my Mac as a Camera?

Tags: macos, mac, camera, monterey

It is very inconvenient for MacBook users to take photos. On Windows, there is the Camera app which can be really useful at times.

How can I use my Mac to take pictures?

Comment: "Why" questions always are difficult to answer, assume you are looking for a tool. Which you already found, but please add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always [Photo Booth.app](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/photo-booth/welcome/mac). I guess it's always going to be a bit awkward to use a laptop as a camera for pictures of anything other than the user.

Answer (score -1):

The question is vague but you might be looking for  [SecuritySpy](https://www.bensoftware.com/securityspy/) and the built-in camera is among the supported ones.

SecuritySpy is an NVR (Network Video Recording) software that lets you turn your built-in camera (among a larger number of supported cameras) into a useful video surveillance system as it feature smart motion detection. Thus letting you put your built-in camera to good use, like taking a video or screenshots when it detects movement.

Comment: Hello, Elio. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.